# problem with get url using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

Sorry if this question may seem easy to some but i cannot seem to figure it out. i was told that i could come here because the guys here are very helpful. i am having problem with the following code. when the uid is call into the url for `example page.php?uid=5` i get "some code" if i do `page.php?uid=letters` i get redirected to `page.php?uid=1`. that works fine. but if a user should enter `page.php?uid=1letters` i get this error..Unknown column '1gh' in 'where clause'

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\page.php on line 173.

i only get this error if the user enters unwanted characters at the end of get url id. How can i prevent this from happen how can i have it redirect to `page.php?uid=1`... see code below

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_GET['uid']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT user.* FROM user WHERE id = '$id'");

if ((mysql_num_rows($query)==0)) {
    header("location:page.php?uid=1");
    die();
}
else {
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $foo = $row['foo'];

        echo "some code";
```

Comment: Why are you using an **`@`** symbol in your $_GET request?

Why not just:

`$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['uid']);`

Just curious...

Comment: Bad attempt at supressing errors/warnings if the 'uid' parameter isn't in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_query returns false on error. You should check what it returns:

```
$query = "SELECT user.* FROM user WHERE id = '$id'"
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result === false) {
    die($query.'<br/>'.mysql_error());
}
```

Then you can understand why it failed. I've added the query to the `die()` statement so you can try the query manually as well.

The error given is **unknown column** of a string, which suggests you are not enclosing the value with single quotes in the SQL query, even though the code in the question does.

In production you should be taking all steps you can to ensure errors are handled gracefully. In this case you will probably want the same behaviour as not finding a user:

```
header("location:page.php?uid=1");
```

Comment: Good suggestion but exiting the process due to a bad query (where the bad part most likely comes from user input) is the wrong approach to handling the error

Comment: I'm not suggesting in production code... I'm suggesting to understand why it failed. Hence the last line. Will clarify it more in the answer.

Comment: @Jacob You still get the upvote for a good answer ;-). Given the error message "boolean given", I'd say you are entirely correct. FYI, my preference is to throw an exception.

Comment: that's how i know the error by using echo mysql_error(). it says Unknown column '1letters' in 'where clause'

Comment: @user In that case, edit your question to show the *real* code

Comment: @user618879 I've added the $query to the `die()` statement. Your query is wrong, so you should be debugging it to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: ok so check this out i follwed the code and it pointed to a different page. this is where is points.

Comment: @user Edit your question to show `C:\wamp\www\page.php` around line 173

Comment: ok so check this out i follwed the code and it pointed to a different page. this is where is points.  $slq = mysql_query(("SELECT friends.*, user_id, email, fname AS ffname, lname AS flname FROM friends, user WHERE friends.toid = user.email AND friends.fromid =(SELECT email FROM user WHERE user_id = $id)UNION ALL SELECT friends.*, user_id, email, fname AS ffname, lname AS flname FROM friends, user WHERE friends.fromid = user.email AND friends.toid =(SELECT email FROM user WHERE user_id = $id)"));

Comment: when i do a echo mysql_error() it output Unknown column '1letters' in 'where clause'. this only happens if i type in page.php?uid=1letters or page.php?uid=2letters , etc

Comment: Your problem is you are passing in $id without surrounding it with single quotes, so it believes $id is a field (if it is a string). You should update your question to reflect the changes.

Comment: thank you jacob, i can't believe i didnt see that, why i say that, because i have a similar query to that one and i didnt get a error at that line because i had placed it in quotation. thanks alot